# Vertical line test and multi-valued function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

According to wikipedia : "If the vertical line you drew intersects the graph more than once for any value of x then the graph is not the graph of a function."
But I read on textbook this: "The point is that the graph of multi-valued  function has the property of doubling back. In other words, this is what is implied when we say that a line parallel to the y axis intersects the graph in more than one point....
Notice that these points of tangency partition the curve into a union of single valued curves"
I don't get it. Does anybody know better explain?

Answer (score 1):

There exists two different concepts of function here.

The wikipedia article uses the concept of a function where it takes in a number (or other mathematical object), or bunch of numbers, and returns a single number.  Thus, each function will pass a vertical line test, and the wikipedia sentence holds for that concept.

A multi-valued function uses the concept where values of the domain get associated to values in a co-domain.  There exists no limitation like with the wikipedia concept of a function.  So, many values could get associated to '6' for some function.

The textbook talking about the union of single valued curves implies that a multi-valued function (on numbers, of course), could get talked about in terms of a union of single-valued functions, where single-valued refers to the number of outputs that a function can produce.